# CK Editor 5 custom build onChange not working

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

I am using ck editor 5 online build tool to build a custom build of CK Editor 5. Successfully added it as a dependency of react project.

Included Mention plugin and other default plugins

```
import Editor from "ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor";

<CKEditor
disabled={props.readOnly}
editor={Editor}
data={props.value ? props.value : ""}
config={{

      readOnly: props.readOnly,
      mention: {
        feeds: [
          {
            marker: "@",
            feed: getPersonByName,
            minimumCharacters: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      toolbar: [],
    }}
  
    onChange={(_event: any, editor: { getData: () => any }) => {
      const data = editor.getData();
      handleChange(editor);
    }}
    onBlur={(_event: any, _editor: any) => {}}
    onFocus={(_event: any, _editor: any) => {}}
  />
```

mention plugin work as expected. but editors onChange event not firing.so I could not get the editor value.
[image]

ckeditor.js:5

```
   CKEditorError: editor-isreadonly-has-no-setter
```

Comment: I also have the same problem when deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the React version to the latest version (18.0.0) would be fixed the issue